# Is there a way to run @after method before IResultListener methods?

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have an listener which implements the methods onTestSuccess and onTestFailure of IResultListener2. In my test I create screenshots in an @after annotated method, which were needed by the listener. But testng calls the methods in the listener before the @after method.

Is there a parameter to run the @after method first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no parameter of such kind.  An after method would be specific to a particular set of cases.  Wouldn't you want that the logic to capture your screenshots be executed for all your cases and not a specific set?  In which case, your screenshot capturing logic should be in your listener methods and any cleanup logic for your specific set of cases should be in after methods.
If there is something specific that you want to do after your aftermethods, then you can try implementing IconfigurationListener, and implement those methods after checking that the invoking method is an aftermethod, something like..

```
public void onConfigurationSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
    if(arg0.getMethod().isAfterMethodConfiguration())...do something;

}
```

Hope it helps..