# Tweak to run @AfterMethod before onTestSuccess/onTestFailure

Tags: java, testng

I would like to know if there's some way to tweak TestNG so that the method annotated by @AfterMethod gets executed first and then onTestSuccess/onTestFailure methods in the test listener run.

In my project, the method annotated by @AfterMethod has the logic to print the response body for each test method. And the onTestSuccess/onTestFailure methods have logic to print a message (e.g. "Test completed"). I do not want to put the code to print this message in the @AfterMethod of every test class in my project.

The problem is, the message "Test completed" is shown first and then the response body gets printed, which might be correct as per the TestNG design, but this is something I want to tweak.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run @after method before IResultListener methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432490/is-there-a-way-to-run-after-method-before-iresultlistener-methods)

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation run listeners first and then before/after methods.

For the moment, you can't change the order of listeners, and before/after methods are not listeners.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run @after method before IResultListener methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432490/is-there-a-way-to-run-after-method-before-iresultlistener-methods) ?

Comment: @nullpointer True, same question. But the answer could not work in new/current versions because such usages are not specified.

Comment: Agreed. Would expect you to answer that and redirect this to it. :)

Comment: @juherr May I know if something has changed in the latest TestNG version which would allow me to achieve this? :)

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure You should open a new feature request on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues

Answer (score 0):

If the main concern, which prevents adding a custom message at the end of `@AfterMethod`, is just a global refactoring you want to avoid, I'd consider AOP techniques. Here's an **AspectJ** sample:

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
public class MessageAspect {

    @After("execution(@org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod * target.package.path..*.*(..))")
    public void print(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("Test completed");
    }
}
```

The main advantage of using AOP in your case is minimal effort with 0-refactoring.

Comment: Could you please elaborate this more with respect to TestNG?

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure not sure I got your question. With AspectJ library you can intercept any method call. Including those, which is annotated with `@AfterMethod`. So you don't even need to create `onTestSuccess` / `onTestFailure` events listener for such trivial logging task. Adding 10 lines of AOP code is much easier than requesting a reordering feature from TestNG community.